# Can i use the rest size of a variable?

Tags: css, less

I have 2 Divs. They are both floating left and div1 has a variable.

```
@div1: 8%;
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="div1">Icon</div>
<div class="div2">Big Text</div>
```

Can I tell the div2 that it has to use the rest of the width? So, in this case that should be 92%. How can I do this without creating a second variable? The 2 divs together have to be 100% wide.

Comment: Yes you can, have you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all seriousness, it would've been faster for you to either try or read the starters manual than to ask this question.

```
@div1: 8%;
.selector {
    width: 100% - @div1; //Evaluates to 92%
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have problems to understand somethings in the documentation. At last i tryed "width: calc(100% - @div1);" and it works! But your version looks clearer than my. Thanks again for this nice answer!